# Stop nav/sidebar from scrolling

Tags: nav, sticky

I'd like the nav bar to stop scrolling once it gets close to the bottom so I can still see the footer. I'm still learning some of these things and I'm sure there are better ways to do it but this is what I have for now.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1000) {
    $('#sticky').addClass('sticky');
  }
  else {
    $('#sticky').removeClass('sticky');
  }
});
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.sticky {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 292.5px;
   background-color: #fff;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
   z-index: 9;
   padding-top: 0;
   padding-bottom: 0;
 }
```

HTML is here at this link. (sorry for the confusion)
http://xmjvn.mdnyd.servertrust.com/

Comment: Could you please provide HTML and CSS source code, or (better) a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @FelixEdelmann HTML code provided - just learned about jsfiddle, will use that next time.

Comment: This is not HTML ...

Comment: @FelixEdelmann Sorry about the confusion. I added a link to the end and here as well. http://xmjvn.mdnyd.servertrust.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  const totalHeight = $(document).height();
  const windowHeight = $(window).height();
  const navHeight = $('#nav').height();
  const footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
  
  if (($(window).scrollTop() + navHeight) < (totalHeight - footerHeight)) {
    $('#nav').addClass('sticky');
  } else {
    $('#nav').removeClass('sticky');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#nav {
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#footer {
  margin-top: 1500px;
  background: tomato;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">nav</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```